# TFS custom argument to modify BuildNumberFormat argument

Tags: tfs

I want to set an argument value in my TFS custom XAML process and use that value in other places.

Notice below...

1. I have created a custom argument called 'TrunkVersion'.
2. I am trying to use that to create the BuildNumberFormat string.

[image]

When I run my build I get...

```
Exception Message: Unable to expand the macro $(TrunkVersion) specified in 
build number format (type InvalidMacroInBuildNumberException)
```

[image]

How can I use the TrunkVersion build argument to compose BuildNumberFormat?

Comment: what you are trying to achieve is possible, I don't think you can do it this way. The `TrunkVersion` is a build Argument, Not a Macro Value

Comment: So how would I use a Build Argument to compose the BuildNumberFormat?

Comment: you will have to modify the template. it is at the top of the template where the build number is set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add the argument into the buildnumber format you will have to modify the template

[image: update build number]

Alternatively you could remove the argument all togetether and just hard code your value into the build number field

`1.0.9$(Rev:.r)`

Comment: Where can I find a list of optional parameters to use in the expression? thanks.